# Developers console has not been activated contact administrator

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a paid account for google app engine, when trying to create a compute engine I'm not able to create a new project, says

> Developers console has not been activated contact administrator

Can't find perfect solution.

*Billing account is active.*

Comment: Sounds like you're using a Google Apps account and your Google Apps Domain administrator forgot to allow a couple of apps.

Comment: Thank you konqi,how can i enable it